# Unity's Input.mousePosition is off by 20px in y direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my player controller's update, I'm doing:

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);
```

I've set the game to `1920x1080` (`Debug.Log(Screen.width + "x" + Screen.height)` confirms that).

The resulting log writes `(960.0, 560.0)` (for the mouse position) while I strongly expect `(960.0, 540.0)` (off by 20px in y direction).

Unity version is `2017.3.0f3 Personal`, OS is Windows 10 x64 if that's relevant.

Is this expected behavior that I somehow missed? Is this a genuine bug that I should report (where?)?

Comment: For y position is it 940 or 540 ?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I expect `540` (`== 1080 / 2`) but got `560`.

Comment: Could it be because you have a bar at the top of the screen? Then compiling with the full screen option should be enough

Comment: Odd, I'm having the same issue, those 20 pixels are always added to the y position of the mouse, regardless of resolution (i.e., if I set 1920x1200, I get y=620) IF the scale of the game window is set to 1. If the scale is higher, those 20 pixels decrease exactly by 20/scale, i.e. if scale is set to 5x, y is reported as 544 (540 + 20/5). Edit: tested in 2018.1.0b5, same results.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc of [CursorLockMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.Locked.html), the lock option will

> Lock cursor to the center of the game window

Note that it says **game window**, not screen. Do you per chance have a 40 pixel menu bar on top of the window? I think that your mouse is in the center of the window, that's is. So that would be to expected behaviour

Comment: I'm just starting it inside the Unity Editor. What is the *game window* in that case?

Comment: the window in which the game is rendered

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons that I see:

- Since you use the Input.MousePosition, perhaps the mouse is placed wrongly somehow? How do you place the mouse position to be at the middle of the screen? It would be good if you displayed this code.
- The mouse cursors hotspot offsets the result 20 pixels, as it is not set correctly according to the mouse set and used. Here is a description of what the hotspot does: **hotspot** The offset from the top left of the texture to use as the target point (must be within the bounds of the cursor).

Source concerning hotspot: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.SetCursor.html

Possible solutions that i see:

- Adjust how you place the mouse location.
- Add a buffer zone variable so you always deduct -20 from the mouse position.
- Adjust the hotspot.

You don't use any raycasts do you? If yes, please show that code.

Comment: Mouse position should be automatically set via `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;`. I'm using raycasts but the problem manifests itself before that (`Input.mousePosition` is already wrong so I don't know how seeing raycast code might help)